# create a float Array with numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a method which generate a array with (float) values at each point.

my current approach:

```
static float[] createFloatArrayWithNumbers(int count){
     float  arr []= new float [count];
     for(int i=0; i<=count; i++){
        arr[i]=i;
     }
     return arr;
}
```

The method returns `[F@6e1408`. but it should not,

For example when `count == 7`, the output are:

```
3.0f,
5.1f,
7.2f,
9.3f,
11.4f,
13.5f,
```

Are the values randomly set?

Comment: Maybe this is due to implicit casting integer variable `i` to float ? but you should re-tag your question with the proper language you're using, although this looks pretty much like C family, could be something else

Comment: Its Java ;). If i set count==7 the method returns [F@6e1408

Comment: Of course it does, arrays are not printable by default. Use a `List` instead, or write your own array printer.

Comment: Use Arrays.toString() in order to print the array.

Comment: I wonder how a float array without numbers might look ......

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java do not override the `toString` method, so you get a default representation. Use `Arrays.toString` to get a useful representation instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```